# Exposing .NET's internal StorageRoot via Reflection for accessing file/stream-based Structured Storage

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

.NET tantalizingly exposes `StorageInfo` and `StreamInfo` as `public` classes, but hides the seminal `StorageRoot` as an `internal` class, leaving the user no way of creating or opening a Structured Storage from a file or stream.

Microsoft's Reference Source details the source behind [`StorageRoot`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#WindowsBase/Base/System/IO/Packaging/CompoundFile/StorageRoot.cs) which inherits from `StorageInfo`, so rather than copy the code, I've chosen to expose the static methods of `StorageRoot` via reflection, so that I can get a reference to the root storage of a `File` or `Stream`. I've also exposed a `Close` method to close an open root `StorageInfo`.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Packaging;
using System.Reflection;

namespace StructuredStoreageTest
{
    public static class StorageRoot
    {
        public static StorageInfo CreateOnStream(Stream baseStream)
        {
            return (StorageInfo)InvokeStorageRootMethod(null, "CreateOnStream", baseStream);
        }

        public static StorageInfo CreateOnStream(Stream baseStream, FileMode mode)
        {
            return (StorageInfo)InvokeStorageRootMethod(null, "CreateOnStream", baseStream, mode);
        }

        public static StorageInfo Open(string path)
        {
            return (StorageInfo)InvokeStorageRootMethod(null, "Open", path);
        }

        public static StorageInfo Open(string path, FileMode mode)
        {
            return (StorageInfo)InvokeStorageRootMethod(null, "Open", path, mode);
        }

        public static StorageInfo Open(string path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access)
        {
            return (StorageInfo)InvokeStorageRootMethod(null, "Open", path, mode, access);
        }

        public static StorageInfo Open(string path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share)
        {
            return (StorageInfo)InvokeStorageRootMethod(null, "Open", path, mode, access, share);
        }

        public static StorageInfo Open(string path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, int sectorSize)
        {
            return (StorageInfo)InvokeStorageRootMethod(null, "Open", path, mode, access, share, sectorSize);
        }

        public static void Close(StorageInfo storageRoot)
        {
            InvokeStorageRootMethod(storageRoot, "Close");
        }

        private static object InvokeStorageRootMethod(StorageInfo storageRoot, string methodName, params object[] methodArgs)
        {
            Type storageRootType = typeof(StorageInfo).Assembly.GetType("System.IO.Packaging.StorageRoot", true, false);
            return storageRootType.InvokeMember(methodName,
                BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | 
                BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.InvokeMethod,
                null, storageRoot, methodArgs);
        }
    }
}
```

I can then use `StorageRoot` as follows:

```
MemoryStream myStream = new MemoryStream(streamBytes);
StorageInfo myRoot = StorageRoot.CreateOnStream(myStream);

StreamInfo dataStreamInfo = myRoot.GetStreamInfo("data");
Stream dataStream = dataStreamInfo.GetStream();
//read/process the stream
dataStream.Dispose();

StorageRoot.Close(myRoot);
```

Is relying upon Reflection the best alternative here? I *could* reproduce the `StorageRoot` code from Reference Source, and make `StorageRoot` an instance class, I suppose.

Comment: What does this solution make possible which isn't doable with the availabale public APIs? I think I'm missing the point of it.

Comment: @t3chb0t it leverages/exposes an existing but `internal` implementation. Using the public API would entail inheriting `StorageInfo` and making an entirely new implementation. This solution enables creating/opening the internal structured storage of - entirely hypothetical idea here - say, an MS-Access form or report, and access things that aren't otherwise accessible, not even through interop assemblies and the host application object model.

Comment: @t3chb0t I could have used the API functions, and I *could* have written my own structured storage parser (the spec is documented), but wrapping an existing implementation seemed easier and guaranteed to be consistent with MS'  handling of structured storage. I wasn't aiming to reinvent the wheel, but rather to make the wheel accessible.

Answer (score 3):

A stream-like class that doesn't implement `IDisposable` and needs to be closed manually, and worked with `static` methods, breaks POLA/POLS.

I would expect to be able to do this:

```
using(var ms = new MemoryStream(bytes))
using(var root = new StorageRoot(ms))
{
    // do stuff
}
```

I like the reflection idea to access these otherwise hidden gems, however in a code base that uses objects in a standard/idiomatic way, I see this one sticking out like a sore thumb.

I'd definitely do whatever it takes to make it work with a proper instance.